# SQL Server: calculate all days per month when no orders?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

Suppose you have orders

```
   | Order |     Date    | 
   -----------------------
   |   1   |   20150101  |
   |   2   |   20150103  |
   |   3   |   20150105  |
   |   11  |   20150211  |
   |   22  |   20150224  |
   |   33  |   20150204  |
```

and the days when no orders are

```
   |  Month  | NoOrdersCount |
   ---------------------------   
   | 201501  |      28       |
   | 201502  |      25       |
```

I want to do this in T-SQL. My first idea is to create table for a year where all days per line and left join this with the orders. Now the sum of NULLs gives us the results of no orders.

How can you calculate the number of `NoOrders` per month from transaction data like the above in SQL Server 2014?

Comment: Column Date's data type?

Comment: Your idea seems good

Comment: Is 27 a typo? Last I checked, most January's have 31 days and I only count 3 days of orders in January

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - Are you joking when you said  `"most" January's have 31 days`?

Comment: @OtoShavadze - mostly tongue-in-cheek. But there are examples. January 1583 if you happened to live in Holland, for example.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever 201501 has 31 days minus 3 orders so 28 days when no orders.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - Ok, thank you, I didn't know that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need an additional table.  All you need is a way to calculate the number of days in a month.  Here is one method:

```
select year(date), month(date),
       (datediff(day,
                 dateadd(day, 1 - day(min(date)), min(date),
                 eomonth(date) + 1 -
        count(distinct date)
       ) as NoOrdersCount
from dates
group by year(date), month(date);
```

As a note:  If you know you will always have one day in the month that is not the 29th, 30th, or 31st, you can use:

```
select year(date), month(date),
       (datediff(day, min(date), dateadd(month, 1, min(date))) -
        count(distinct date)
       ) as NoOrdersCount
from dates
group by year(date), month(date);
```

Answer (score 1):

One more way to get the `day` of the month end date and subtracting the number of distinct dates when there were orders.

```
select distinct year(date),month(date),
day(eomonth(date)) - (select count(distinct date) from orders o2
                      where year(o2.date)=year(o1.date) 
                      and month(o2.date)=month(o1.date))
from orders o1
```

Counting can be done with a window function, but `distinct` isn't allowed.

Comment: Thank you, I tested this to work [here](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/657892/sql-ms-select-days-when-no-orders-and-count-them).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this should do it for you.

```
select convert(char(6), date, 112) as Month,
       day(eomonth(min(date))) - count(distinct date) as NoOrdersCount
from dates
group by convert(char(6), date, 112);
```